# Laravel Join Using Eloquent Relations

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have four models created, and their relations have been defined correctly. What I haven't grasped is how to use those relations for my situation.

Let's use `countries` > `regions` > `cities` > `censuses` as a contrived example of the relations. I can get the most recent date a census was taken on with this function in the `Census` model:

```
public static function getMaxTakenOn($country_id)
{
   return \DB::table('regions')
        ->join('cities', 'cities.region_id', '=', 'region.id')
        ->join('censuses', 'censuses.city_id', '=', 'cities.id')
        ->where('regions.country_id', '=', $country_id)
        ->max('censuses.taken_on');
}
```

How would I rewrite the function body to use the Eloquent Relations?

Comment: You joined all these three tables and made a custom query. Eloquent relations won't help you too much in this situation.

Comment: I'd like to know why I'm getting downvotes. I have a well-defined question with code examples.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `hasMany` and a custom field in each of the models:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships

Example in your Regions model, you will need a:

```
public function cities() {
 return $this->hasMany('App\Cities');
}
```

Then so on in your other models.

Once that is done, you don't need the 2 joins, you can access them like:

```
$region = new Region();
$region->where('country_id', '=', $country_id)
->max('censuses.taken_on');

echo $region->cities()->censuses()->count();
```

Comment: I have those Relations defined. I don't know how to use them.

Comment: Edited an example

Comment: Your example is missing the intermediary `City` model at the very least.

Comment: It's right there? In the last line. Also it's an example, not expecting it to be exactly what you want..

Comment: I get 'Column not found' errors. I'm thinking that Eloquent is simply not designed to work like this.